# Play Scala Framework Error

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to run the project activator-hello-play-2_3-scala-master  (available at typesafe's git repo) but I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.typesafe.sbt.web.Import$WebKeys$.pipelineStages()Lsbt/SettingKey

Even if I run templates such as hello-play-scala Framework 2.3 from activator ui, I get the same error.

I am using activator 1.3.4-minimal. Could you please suggest what might be going wrong?

Here is my complete stack trace:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.sbt.web.Import$WebKeys$.pipelineStages()Lsbt/SettingKey;
>       at com.typesafe.sbt.gzip.SbtGzip$.projectSettings(SbtGzip.scala:32)
>       at sbt.Load$$anonfun$autoPluginSettings$1$1.apply(Load.scala:666)
>       at sbt.Load$$anonfun$autoPluginSettings$1$1.apply(Load.scala:666)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
>       at sbt.Load$.autoPluginSettings$1(Load.scala:666)
>       at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$expandSettings$1(Load.scala:681)
>       at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$expandSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:682)
>       at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$expandSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:682)
>       at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
>       at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:34)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:138)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.$div$colon(Traversable.scala:105)
>       at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$expandSettings$1(Load.scala:682)
>       at sbt.Load$.resolveProject(Load.scala:684)
>       at sbt.Load$.finalizeProject$1(Load.scala:549)
>       at sbt.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:577)
>       at sbt.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:442)
>       at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:446)
>       at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
>       at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
>       at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
>       at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
>       at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
>       at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:334)
>       at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:289)
>       at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:285)
>       at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:276)
>       at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:130)
>       at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:36)
>       at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:481)
>       at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
>       at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
>       at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
>       at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
>       at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
>       at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
>       at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
>       at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
>       at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
>       at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
>       at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
>       at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
>       at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
>       at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
>       at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)

Comment: Hi, I figured out that there are a lot of incompatibilities with using Java version 7 and before. But I had the constraint to work on JDK7 so in order to get going with play, I installed play-2.2.6.zip from Playframework.org and it worked fine. For people who wish to use the play framework with activator, I reckon you use the latest version with JDK 8